# Android: how to prevent relayout of entire hierarchy when a View is updated?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have the following hierarchy:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="example.com.hellorelayout.MainActivity"
>

<example.com.hellorelayout.MyFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:tag="frame1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello 1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</example.com.hellorelayout.MyFrameLayout>

<example.com.hellorelayout.MyFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:background="#ff0"
    android:tag="frame2"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello 2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</example.com.hellorelayout.MyFrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Every time I update one of the TextViews the all the views are laid out (i.e. onLayout() and onGlobalLayout() of both FrameLayouts are triggered).

I expect this not to happen because FrameLayouts have fixed width and height.

So... what's going on? How can I prevent onLayout() to be called on the Views? BTW if I use match_parent in the TextViews it works but this isn't feasible since this is a simplification of a scenario in which I have no control over the TextView.

Comment: maybe give the TextView the fixed size ... (and then you'd remove it's layout_gravity and use gravity instead)

Comment: TextView is there as an example but any View that calls requestLayout() has the same effect.